# performance of .Primitive and .Internal

Tags: r

I was doing some optimization by removing one step from the process:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(paste0("this","and","that"))
Unit: microseconds
                          expr   min    lq    mean median    uq    max neval
 paste0("this", "and", "that") 2.026 2.027 3.50933  2.431 2.837 34.038   100

> microbenchmark(.Internal(paste0(list("this","and","that"),NULL)))
Unit: microseconds
                                                 expr   min    lq    mean median    uq    max neval
 .Internal(paste0(list("this", "and", "that"), NULL)) 1.216 1.621 2.77596  2.026 2.027 43.764   100
```

So far so good.

But then after I noticed that `list` was defined as

```
function (...)  .Primitive("list")
```

I tried to further "simplify"

```
> microbenchmark(.Internal(paste0(.Primitive("list")("this","and","that"),NULL)))
Unit: microseconds
                                                               expr   min    lq    mean median    uq    max neval
 .Internal(paste0(.Primitive("list")("this", "and", "that"), NULL)) 3.241 3.242 4.66433  3.647 3.648 80.638   100
```

and the time increases!

my guess is that processing the string `"list"` is the source of the problem, and that it's handled differently within the actual calling of the function `list`

but how?

*disclaimer: I know this hurts readability more than it helps performance. This is just for some very simple functions that will not change and are used so often that slight performance issues are desired even at this cost.*

---

Edit in response to Josh O'Brien's comment:

I'm not sure what this says about his idea, but

```
library(compiler)
ff <- compile(function(...){.Internal(paste0(.Primitive("list")("this","and","that"),NULL))})
ff2 <- compile(function(...){.Internal(paste0(list("this","and","that"),NULL))})
microbenchmark(eval(ff),eval(ff2),times=10000)
> microbenchmark(eval(ff2),eval(ff),times=10000)
Unit: microseconds
      expr   min    lq     mean median    uq     max neval
 eval(ff2) 1.621 2.026 2.356761  2.026 2.431 144.257 10000
  eval(ff) 1.621 2.026 2.455913  2.026 2.431  89.148 10000
```

and looking at the plot generated from microbenchmark (just wrap it with `plot()` to see it yourself) running that a bunch of times, it appears that those have statistically identical performance, despite that "max" value looking like ff2 has a worse worst-case. I don't know what to make of that, but maybe that will help someone. So all that basically says that they compile to identical code. Does that mean his comment is the answer?

Comment: Could it be due to the fact that the body of `base::list()` is byte-compiled whereas your last block requires evaluation of a function call (`.Primitive("list")`) to arrive at the same point as you get by just evaluating the symbol `list`? It's just speculation on my part, but it seems like one advantage of byte compilation would be that R wouldn't actually have to evaluate a call to `.Primitive(".list")` to find the entry point into C code each and every time it uses the function `list`...

Comment: The "max" case is often a one-off outlier due to some random event on your computer causing a wait for a resource, or  some daemon getting in the way of RAM temporarily, etc.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: I don't understand your comment. `base::list` is a primitive and is defined as `function(...) .Primitive("list")`, and therefore has no body to byte compile.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Well, there's a reason my sentences started with "Could it be..." and then "It's just speculation on my part...". But what I'm referring to as the body is the part that reads `.Primitive("list")`, which looks to me like it would involve some sort of call to `.Primitive`, in which it searches for a C-level function corresponding to the R character string `"list"`. When I do `is(substitute(.Primitive("mist")))`, it tells me that that's a function call, and my understanding is that function calls are relatively expensive, time-wise.

Comment: Anyway, my thought/hunch was that byte-compilation would in effect do that lookup once, would find the address of that C-level function and store that, and that future calls to the byte-compiled `list` function could just use that address rather than having to evaluate whatever you'd like to call what happens when you ask R to evaluate `.Primitive("list")`.

Comment: Trying to put it one other way: when I do `is(substitute(.Primitive("mist")))`, it tells me that that's a function call, and my understanding is that function calls are relatively expensive, time-wise. That's the call that I thought byte-compilation might avoid. And the following test *seems* to confirm that the call to `.Primitive` *is* indeed avoided by using the byte compiled `list` rather than `.Primitive("list")`: `trace(.Primitive); list(4); .Primitive("list")(4)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason `.Internal(paste0(.Primitive("list")("this","and","that"),NULL))` is slower seems to be because of what [Josh O'Brien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980833/josh-obrien) guessed. Calling `.Primitive("list")` directly incurs some additional overhead.

You can see the effects via a simple example:

```
require(compiler)
pl <- cmpfun({.Primitive("list")})
microbenchmark(list(), .Primitive("list")(), pl())
# Unit: nanoseconds
#                  expr  min     lq median     uq   max neval
#                list()   63   98.0  112.0  140.5   529   100
#  .Primitive("list")() 4243 4391.5 4486.5 4606.0 16077   100
#                  pl()   79  135.5  148.0  175.5 39108   100
```

That said, you're not going to be able to improve the speed of `.Primitive` and `.Internal` from the R prompt. They are both entry points to C code.

And there's no reason to try and replace a call to `.Primitive` with `.Internal`. That's recursive, since `.Internal` *is* itself a primitive.

```
> .Internal
function (call)  .Primitive(".Internal")
```

You'll get the same slowness if you try to call `.Internal` "directly"... and a similar "speedup" if you compile the "direct" call.

```
Internal. <- function() .Internal(paste0(list("this","and","that"),NULL))
Primitive. <- function() .Primitive(".Internal")(paste0("this","and","that"),NULL)
cPrimitive. <- cmpfun({Primitive.})
microbenchmark(Internal., Primitive., cPrimitive., times=1e4)
# Unit: nanoseconds
#         expr min lq median uq  max neval
#    Internal.  26 27     27 28 1057 10000
#   Primitive.  28 32     32 33 2526 10000
#  cPrimitive.  26 27     27 27 1706 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

The R interpreter has hardcoded optimizations for common functions, and this goes deeper than byte compiling:

```
> list2 <- list
> list3 <- cmpfun(list2)
> microbenchmark(
+   list(1,2),
+   list2(1,2),
+   list3(1,2)
+ )
Unit: nanoseconds
        expr min    lq    mean median    uq   max neval
  list(1, 2) 576 620.5  654.53  640.0 675.5   941   100
 list2(1, 2) 619 702.0 1123.43  728.0 761.0 39045   100
 list3(1, 2) 617 683.0  735.83  715.5 759.0  1964   100
```

Here's what the SEXPs look like. Note the metadata on "list"

```
> .Internal(inspect(quote(list(1,2))))
@23b0ed0 06 LANGSXP g0c0 [NAM(2)] 
  @1ed8f48 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "list" (has value)
  @2c7adf8 14 REALSXP g0c1 [] (len=1, tl=0) 1
  @2c7adc8 14 REALSXP g0c1 [] (len=1, tl=0) 2
```

`list2` is missing some metadata:

```
> list2 <- list
> .Internal(inspect(quote(list2(1,2))))
@23b1578 06 LANGSXP g0c0 [NAM(2)] 
  @23b0a70 01 SYMSXP g0c0 [] "list2"
  @2c7ad08 14 REALSXP g0c1 [] (len=1, tl=0) 1
  @2c7acd8 14 REALSXP g0c1 [] (len=1, tl=0) 2
```

`.Primitive("list")` is a more complicated expression:

```
> .Internal(inspect(quote(.Primitive("list")(1,2))))
@297e748 06 LANGSXP g0c0 [NAM(2)] 
  @297d9a0 06 LANGSXP g0c0 [] 
    @1ec4530 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] ".Primitive" (has value)
    @2c7a888 16 STRSXP g0c1 [] (len=1, tl=0)
      @1ed5588 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "list"
  @2c7a858 14 REALSXP g0c1 [] (len=1, tl=0) 1
  @2c7a828 14 REALSXP g0c1 [] (len=1, tl=0) 2
```

Comment: Hmm. I don't think those benchmarks are displaying actually significant differences, especially since `list2` is identical to `list`. `list2` is not a copy of `list`: they both literally point to the same location as can be seen by doing `list2 <- list; .Internal(inspect(list)); .Internal(inspect(list2))`.

Comment: Try it yourself :)  I think the difference is in the interpretation of the code, not the code itself.

Also take a look here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/565868293e125eb1a4f68fa149e2d24963edf781/src/main/eval.c#L5351-L5389

`list2` is a variable, has to be searched from the global up; `list` is a builtin and can be pulled out of the builtin table.

Comment: I did try it, and for some reason (?) get warning messages like `" Could not measure a positive execution time for 949 evaluations."` along with highly variable results that show sometimes one and sometimes the other one winning. That said, I don't know anything about the speed of looking up variables in different locations. My first, naive, thought *would* have been that a symbol in `.GlobalEnv` would be found faster (if there is any difference at all) than one at the end of the search path in `"package:base"`. But I'm admittedly in over my head on these C-level details of R's operation!

Comment: I'm always skeptical of trials in the sub-millisecond range.  Can you retry with a large enough  set of input arguments that each execution takes a more reasonable amount of time?

Comment: use the "times" argument to evaluate more than 100 times, first of all. I got 39,505 zero-time evaluations out of 300,000 evaluations, so this doesn't work for me either...

Comment: @hedgedandlevered -- I think Carl's also getting at another impt. issue, which is that he thinks benchmarking can be unreliable when each individual computation being benchmarked takes so little time! On the issue of 'zero' time-evaluations, I think my Windows machine doesn't measure time increments (or at least make those measurements available to microbenchmark) at the sub-microsecond (nanosecond), which is why I got 949 'zero' measurements out of `times=1000`.