Why are different variations of wrapping base R functions faster/slower?
I am wrapping a number of R functions in a library (purely for syntax consistency with other systems, not performance or anything else). Something like:
ABS_1 <- function (x) { abs(x) }
ABS_2 <- function (x) { .Primitive("abs")(x) }

And I noticed this:
x <- 1e5

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(abs(x), ABS_1(x), ABS_2(x), times = x)

Unit: nanoseconds
     expr min  lq                   mean median  uq     max neval
   abs(x)   0   0  51.100760000065896804      0   0 4464203 1e+05
 ABS_1(x)  41 123 142.329860000001815479    123 123  326196 1e+05
 ABS_2(x) 287 369 398.285890000000563305    369 369  532426 1e+05

I understand there is overhead when wrapping abs(), but what explains the performance difference between the two wrapping functions ?
This difference doesn't seem to scale when computing the function on a vector instead:
n <- 1e5
x <- 1:n

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(abs(x), ABS_1(x), ABS_2(x), times = n)

Unit: microseconds
     expr   min    lq  mean median    uq   max neval
   abs(x) 7.626 24.03 51.25  24.68 27.18 59664 1e+05
 ABS_1(x) 7.790 24.19 52.38  24.89 27.31 59591 1e+05
 ABS_2(x) 8.036 24.48 50.11  25.21 27.55 58694 1e+05

I am simply curious what causes the difference.

There's a 4th test directly calling .Primitive("abs")(x), e.g. microbenchmark::microbenchmark(.Primitive("abs")(x), abs(x), ABS_1(x), ABS_2(x), times = x). Anyways, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194281/performance-of-primitive-and-internal seems to be addressing the same question.

I guess the mashine time is spent for resolving .Primitive("abs") to abs(x). When you call it on a vector the major mashine time is used for the calculation of abs(). .Primitive("abs") is resolved once for the whole long vector and so this tiny time delay does not significantly affect the whole result thus making the result dependant on other circumstances. For the first sample for one abs() call your processor resolves .Primitive("abs") also one time

Profiling on the nanosecond level is highly susceptible to "noise," i.e. all sorts of interruptions in the CPU or  CPU--memory  operations on the hardware.
